# How can i add a custom button to a kendo grid in a razor pages .net core 3.1 project that opens a new page

Tags: c#, .net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, razor-pages

I have an ajax bound kendo grid that is view only, reading a number of fields from a larger db model called Notes.

I need a link or a button on each row that will open the edit page so that all fields can be edited, note just the ones in the grid, and pass it an id and possibly another parameter as well. The edit page includes a number of many to many drop downs and treeviews etc.

Being an ajax bound grid, I believe you can only use ClientTemplate, not Template in a bound column if that is the way to do it.

Using a razor pages project with .NETCore3.1, so there isn't a controller, and the page I'm in is Index.cshtml, backed by Index.cshtml.cs

Any help very much appreciated, I'm a bit new to this. Thanks

This is the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Note>().Name("grid")
                    .Groupable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .Scrollable()
                    .ToolBar(x =>
                    {                       
                        x.Excel();
                    })
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(p => p.NoteDate).Title("Note Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Title("Title");
                            columns.Bound(p => p.NoteText).Title("Note Detail");
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Amount).Title("Amount");
                            columns.Bound(p => p.DateCreated).Title("Created");
                            //something like this, but this just takes me to the page im already on
                            columns.Bound(p => p.ID).ClientTemplate(
                                "<a href='" +
                                    Url.Action("Edit", "/Notes/Edit") +
                                    "'/#= ID #'" +
                                ">Edit</a>"
                            );

                            columns.Command(column =>
                            {

                                //Or something like this
                                //column.Custom("Edit").Click("Open Notes/Edit")
                                            //.HtmlAttributes(new { @Id = "#= ID" });}).Width(166);   
                            });
                        })

                    .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
                        .Read(r => r.Url("/Notes/Index?handler=Read").Data("forgeryToken"))
                        .Model(m => m.Id(id => id.ID))
                        .PageSize(10)
                    )
                    .Pageable()
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple ways you can do this. This way probably gives you the most flexibility and is my favorite:

```
columns.Template("<a class='btn' href='javascript:myJavascriptAjaxFunction(#=ID#)'>Edit</a>");
```

If you'd like to use the column command route, first you'll have to make your grid editable, then you'll have to use the edit command, and then you'll want to create an event which will call the Javascript function where you can write your code. The Javascript function will pass in an parameter, such as "e", which you can then use to access information such as the row's model information.

There are 3 types of editing: batch, inline, or popup.Which type of editing will determine the event. Here's Kendo's demo documentation for some good example: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-popup

And here's an example with popup editing:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Note>().Name("grid")
                .Groupable()
                .Sortable()
                .Scrollable()
                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
                .Events(e=>e.Edit("myJavascriptAjaxFunction"))
                .ToolBar(x =>
                {
                    x.Excel();
                })
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.NoteDate).Title("Note Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Title("Title");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.NoteText).Title("Note Detail");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.Amount).Title("Amount");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.DateCreated).Title("Created");
                        //something like this, but this just takes me to the page im already on
                        columns.Bound(p => p.ID).ClientTemplate(
                            "<a href='" +
                                Url.Action("Edit", "/Notes/Edit") +
                                "'/#= ID #'" +
                            ">Edit</a>"
                        );


                        columns.Command(column => column.Edit());
                    })

                .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
                    .Read(r => r.Url("/Notes/Index?handler=Read").Data("forgeryToken"))
                    .Model(m => m.Id(id => id.ID))
                    .PageSize(10)
                )
                .Pageable()
    )
```

**Update:**
Again multiple ways you can go about this, but one way is to use your Javascript function to make an ajax call that returns a partial view  that you could display in a bootstrap modal.

Bootstrap Modal Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Be sure you have bootstrap included in your project and add this to your razor view:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your Javascript:

```
myJavascriptFunction(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", //make sure matches your controller http request
        url: "/Notes/Edit/"+id
        success: function (content) {
            $('.modal-body').html(content);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); //to show the modal
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Vividly. Unfortunately I have no idea what the JavascriptAjaxFunction would like, any clues? Seems like it should be an easy thing to do, but the answer is pretty elusive.

Comment: This is the page I'm trying to navigate to in the case of ID = 2 on my localhost: https://localhost:44370/Notes/Edit/2. I can't really edit in the grid or in a popup easily because there are a number of many to many relationships including hierarchies etc to deal with so I'd rather go to the main Edit page which already has that functionality

Comment: You can add an Ajax call directly to your Javascript. I've added some sample code that should get you started. You may want to add a breakpoint to the controller to make sure your Ajax gets there (and passes up the id correctly). You'll want to return a partial view. There's also a good chance your using a layout page, so be sure to set layout="" in your partial view razor.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate your efforts. I actually ground out a couple of workarounds in the end that are a bit simpler, but I'll flag your answer, it did help me understand the js function better. I used columns.template to show a link, and formatted it as a button:`columns.Template("<a id='a-pretend-button' href='/Notes/Edit/#=ID#'>Edit</a>" +
        "<a id='a-pretend-button' href='/Notes/Delete/#=ID#'>Delete</a>");`